# Wordpress - how detect if current page is the login page

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a better way than using global variable `$pagenow` to detect current page if it is login page, like a `is_admin()` function?

```
if ($pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin())
{
    // Do something
}
```

There is a global variable `$current_screen` with a getter `get_current_screen()` (which is declared in `/wp-admin/includes/template.php`) but it's always equal to `null`.

On [#15686 (Detect the current page template tag) – WordPress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15686) it says `$pagenow` it is usually used, but I think is not a good way to compare non-dynamic pages against the file's name instead of the function (like admin page).

Comment: I suppose there is no existing better solution than using `$pagenow`. I found some people asking to implement `is_login()` conditional tag to customize login page:
http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/custom-login-screen

Answer (score 53, accepted):

While I tend to agree with others on the need for a function is_login_page() or something similar, I found what seems to be the best answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12863/check-if-were-on-the-wp-login-page, which I used to make the following:

```
<?php
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The theme I'm using checked for `!is_admin()` and threw all the JS/CSS onto the login page. m(

Comment: JS/CSS should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts` `admin_enqueue_scripts` or `login_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: Note that `wp-register.php` is not used any more in up-to-date versions of WordPress. See the linked answer in wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Except that only works if the login page hasn't been redirected for security....

Answer (score 4):

If you are like me, and you actually tried to de-register / mess with the jQuery that WordPress automatically loads, then the correct answer is:

**Don't** use `wp_print_styles` to register your scripts – use **[wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)** instead!

This hook will run *only* on the frontend, *not* on the login page, so there's no need for workarounds.

Nacin is explaining it here:
http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/

Comment: This seems like an answer to a different question?

Comment: Maybe – but it’s possible that the requester was trying to do exactly that: “detect if current page is the login page” in order to avoid some conflict on the login page, caused by JavaScript loaded using 'wp_print_styles'. By using 'wp_enqueue_scripts' instead, there's no need anymore for extra rules for the login page.

Comment: PS: the requester said it in his answer to another comment: “I use it for include some JavaScript files on all page which are not admin or login pages”. Therefore my answer is actually very valid – it's the recommended WordPress way of including JavaScript, and makes his attempt at detecting the login page redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you explain what are you going to do with it? So I can tell if you should code using wordpress hooks.

or you can use the absolute uri, just match it with wp-login.php

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $uri;
```

?>

Comment: I use it for include some JavaScript files on all page which are not admin or login pages :

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to be as non WP independant as possible; for instance in a plugin keeping future changes out of scope. You can use something like this:

```
function is_login_page() {
    return !strncmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-login.php', strlen('/wp-login.php'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above ways will not work if someone uses a plugin to change his login page URL. If your login page URL is changed by any security plugin like (Lockdown WP Amin) or similar plugins then you may use this advanced full function. It's my best way now:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------
//Check if we are inside the login page or not
//---------------------------------------------------------------
function is_inside_login_page()
{
    //true if login page URL is still normal
    if(in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php'))) return true;
    
    //true if login page URL is changed by some security plugins
    if(has_action('login_init')) return true;
    
    //Else if nothing above happens >> return false
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the programmer -Mohammed alagha- for this important line
`if(has_action('login_init')) return true;`

Thank you