# PHP user logged in and certain page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this in my wordpress theme in my header.php to display a block of html that I want to show to users that are not logged in.

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! ( is_page( '/register' ) || is_page( '/login' ) ) ) {
echo '';
} else {
echo '<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
       <div class="well" style="width:1040px;margin:0    auto;background:#fbfbfb;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <h3>Welcome, visitor!</h3>
  <p style="color:#999;">Welcome to autospot.it the automotive social network! <a href="http://autospot.it/about">Learn more...</p>
  <p><a href="http://www.autospot.it/register/" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Register</a> - or - <a href="http://www.autospot.it/login/" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">Login</a> 
  </div>
      </div>';
} 
?>
```

This works fine but I would also like for it not to be shown on the login page and the register page.

Comment: How do I add that to this code?

Comment: `header.php` isn't used on the default login/registration page. Do you have custom front end login and reg pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress - how detect if current page is the login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266945/wordpress-how-detect-if-current-page-is-the-login-page)

Comment: I know how to stop it being shown on the wp-login.php but I have custom pages for the login and register pages.

Comment: The code in the duplicate seems to cover the register page as well. Not sure about the custom page business, are they named `register.php`? Try changing the detection code by removing the `wp-` in front of each page name

Comment: no they are http://autospot.it/login and http://autospot.it/register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to detect your front-end login and registration pages:

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! ( is_page( 'register' ) || is_page( 'login' ) ) ) {
        echo '<div>Some stuff here</div>'; // your code
    }
?>
```

Comment: This sort of worked but it shows when user is logged in not logged out!

Comment: Inspect the code carefully, don't forget the `!` negation before `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: I've updated the code above to show what I have now

Comment: you do not need to `echo '';`, just use the code provided in my answer, and echo the html where is says "your code"